# EXTJS 4: Selective Ajax Request Aborting

Tags: ajax, extjs4, request, abort

In my application I have many ajax request that executes every now and then. I have one that executes with a settimeout another is with a user interaction. My problem is the user interaction part.

The scenario is when the user sets the parameter and clicks the button it executes a ajax request. If he makes a mistake  with its parameter the user will adjust something and then execute again the ajax request, with the previous request still on going.

I want to abort the previous request without using the abortall() because like I said before there are other request that should not be interrupted. So its like selecting a request to abort. How do I do that? Please Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a property on [Ext.Ajax](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax) [`autoAbort : Boolean`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-property-autoAbort)

> Whether a new request should abort any pending requests.
>
> Defaults to: false
>
> Available since: 1.1.0

set this prop to `true` on your Ajax sent by user, so it will not interfere with `setInterval` ajax's. Also, **make sure** that you have a [client side](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.VTypes) and a server side validation, so bad params will be avoided. Solving bad params on client side is much quicker, cheaper and user friendly thing to do than let user submit falsy data!

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    params: {
        id: 1
    },
    autoAbort : true, 
    success: function(response){        
          //do something
    },
    failure:function(response){
         //do something
    }
});
```

### Here is [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ingol/zGb4e/) on fiddle!

Comment: Wow that was one real neat fiddle. Nice. Thank you for that. That was what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Problem, is there a autoabort on Ext Store? I am using store with ajax proxy.

Comment: No, but you can override 'doRequest' method on Ajax Proxy with Ext.Ajax call and set autoAbort property to true.

Comment: Does it autoAbort all pending requests, or only those to the same URL for example? So if I am doing a search, I might not want to abort unrelated requests.

Comment: @Alex , no it does not. It only aborts the request on which autoAbort is set. Take a look at the source code of Ext.data.Connection

Comment: @DuvorZubak maybe things have changed since this was posted, but as of Ext 6.6.0 `autoAbort: true` will kill any pending requests that were initiated via `Ext.Ajax.request`.  See the `createRequest` method in the [Ext.data.Connection source](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/src/Connection.js.html)